# Map result from api to observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, async-pipe

I'm trying to map response from API as shown below using Rxjs

In service i have the following

```js
export interface Response {
  data: Array<Data>;
  headers: Headers
}

public fetchData(): Observable<Response> {
   return http.get<Response>(myurl);
}
```

In my component I would like to map the response to the following observables

```js
headers$: Observable<Headers>;
data$: Observable<Array<Data>>;

onInit(){
   myservice.fetchData()
     .pipe(
        //mapping response to the two observables here
     )
}
```

So that i would be able bind my `data$` observable using async pipe in my template as follows

```js
<div *ngIf="let item of data$ | async">
   {{ Whatever }}
</div>
```

Comment: what is the shape of data you receive from http call? I am asking because I believe Response interface should change

Comment: I get an object with two items 1. headers object 2. list of data items e.g ```{ headers: { } , data : [ ] }```

Comment: Do you need only data? and not headers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate a stream using rxjs operators but in your case, you need to intialize your observables with a given stream.

The quick solution would be to map each observable to the wanted infromation :

```
headers$: Observable<Headers>;
data$: Observable<Array<Data>>;

onInit(){
  this.headers$ = this.myService.fetchData().pipe(stream => stream.headers);
  this.data$ = this.myService.fetchData().pipe(stream => stream.data)

}
```

But it means you will make two http calls each time your component is rendered.

A better solution would be to use a Smart / Dump architecture coupled with the async pipe :

Parent component :

```
response$: Observable<Response>;

onInit(){
  this.response$ = this.myService.fetchData();

}
```

Parent template :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="response$ | async as response"
  <app-child [response]="response"></app-child>
</ng-container>
```

Child component :

```
@Input() response: Response
```

Child template :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of response.data">
   {{ Whatever }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rxjs `map` operator to acheive what you need as shown below:

```js
headers$: Observable<Headers>;
data$: Observable<Array<Data>>;

onInit(){
   const response = this.myservice.fetchData();
   this.headers$ = response.pipe(map(resp => resp.headers));
   this.data$ = response.pipe(map(resp => resp.data));
}
```

Now you can use the `data$` and `header$` observables along with `async` pipe in Template file to display the respective data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are only interested in the observable, so I'd recommend you to suscribe to your fetchData method. And then you can map that response. For example:

```
myservice.fetchData().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        //Map your response here  
      }
    )
```

Also another option, is that you can map in your fetchData method instead of doing it in the component.

Comment: the point is to subscribe to the observable with the async pipe so it won't help to subscribe inside the component